# Property 'tip' does not exist on type 'typeof @types/d3/index"'

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I can not use the the d3 tip.

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import  "d3-tip";

var tool_tip = d3.tip()
```

I receive a such error.

```
Property 'tip' does not exist on type 'typeof "/home/viktor/projects/internet_trading_platform/client/node_modules/@types/d3/index"'.
```

I have imported the d3 tip modules have to augment the d3 module. But it does not. According to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Regards.

The d3-tip declaration is located here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-tip/index.d.ts

Answer (score 2):

try this.

```
import d3Tip from "d3-tip"

const tip = d3Tip();

tip.attr("class", "d3-tip")
   .html(d => { return "html"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer but for anyone who has come across this issue, a solution that worked for me is

Import the d3Tip as normal

```
import * as d3Tip from 'd3-tip';
```

then when initialising the tip

```
var tipObject = (<any>d3Tip)()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .html('Loading...');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have been getting this for a long while and just thought on a workaround for it:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

Object.defineProperty(d3, 'tip', {
  value: require('d3-tip')
});
```

Or if you prefer no `require()` statements at all:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3Tip from 'd3-tip';

Object.defineProperty(d3, 'tip', {
  value: d3Tip
});
```

This way TypeScript won't complain anymore.
It also works fine with `@types/d3@3` and `@types/d3-tip@3`.